# Rewrite an html="#" gotoproduct(900) into an actual html link

Tags: php, html

I am new to php. On a product page where users can click to go to the detailed product page I currently see:

Current:
`<a href="#" onclick="return gotoProduct(901)"> <p class="button">Show</p></a>`

I should however have this on the page where the products are listed:

Desired: `<a href="mycompany.com/boot901"> <p class="button">Show</p></a>`

the "gotoProduct" executes gotoProduct(".$row["shoeID"].") — selecting the row in the db corresponding to the shoe id.

How can I achieve the desired result?

Thank you

Comment: why don't you just use href? Don't you have this $row["shoeId"] variable why you are trying to render the page? You have 901 arent you?

Comment: You need to show us a bit more of how the current link is generated in PHP. Otherwise we cannot give you an useful answer, that you can understand.

Comment: I'll try to find and will update. Thanks